# connection between the statistical properties of a scalar field and its columns

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a scalar field $s:[0,1]^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ and its "column" field
\begin{equation}
c: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \mapsto \int_0^1 s(x,y,z) \,\mathrm{d}z.
\end{equation}.

1. What can be said about the statistical properties of $c$ if we consider the statistics of $s$ as given?
2. Conversely, how can the statistical properties of $c$ constrain those of $s$?

For the concrete application, only the field $s$ is physically meaningful, but one only has access to the field $c$. I am interested in both the general case and in the particular situation when $s$ is assumed to be lognormal.

Answer (score 2):

When you mention "statistical properties", perhaps you mean the following: Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent random variables (r.v.'s), each uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. Let $s\colon[0,1]^3\to\mathbb R$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $\text{E}\,|V|<\infty$, where $V:=s(X,Y,Z)$. Let $W:=\text{E}\,(V|Y,Z)$. How are the probability distributions of the r.v.'s $V$ and $W$ related to each other?

An answer to this question is that, by Jensen's inequality, $\text{E}\,f(V)\ge \text{E}\,f(W)$ for any convex function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$; in particular, $\text{Var}\,V\ge\text{Var}\,W$. I think this is all that can be said in such generality.